# Can a gpu and cpu drain power from motherboard and cause auto restart?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power-supply, gpu, undervolting

When trying to play some games my pc freezes and restarts.

the cause is motherboard under-voltage(code 41).
when I checked my psu it maintained a constant voltage no matter what happened.
Even when my pc freezes the psu voltage doesn’t change.

Could it be because my gpu and cpu require more power than my motherboard can support.

Psu: 550w

Motherboard: gigabyte ga-f2a78m-hd2 3.1

Gpu: msi Gtx 1050ti

Cpu: a10-7890k

Comment: How did you test the voltage? Load affects voltage so you cant just probe connectors while they are unplugged and get accurate results.

Comment: I had a multimeter to check voltage while pc was running.

Comment: @John - That isn’t an accurate measurement of voltage due to the fact there are multiple rails.  Most of the contacts for a CPU cannot be reached by your probe.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the motherboard's power delivery system may be failing, however I'd still recommend checking other things first.

First, If you have any over-clocking setup on the CPU or GPU, disable that and see if that resolves the issues.  Overclocking will cause the components to draw more power which the power supply or motherboard may not be able to support.

Second, try a different power supply anyway first.  The low-voltage event may happen to quickly to be detectable with a simple multi-meter, or you may not be measuring in the proper area.  You can swap the power supply with a compatible one from another system if you (or a friend) has one, or get a fairly cheap one online to test with.

If none of the above resolves the issue then you may be dealing with a failing motherboard.  If that's the case, it'd probably be better to look into a full system upgrade rather than just trying to replace the motherboard.